# postgres databases on different partitions

Tags: windows, postgresql

Is it possible to work with different postgresql databases on different partitions? What I mean is that I'd like to keep one database on my SSD drive (in the default pgsql data folder on system partition C:) and I'd like to keep another DB on an external USB HDD, and I would like to being able to work with both databases when I connect to the postgresql server. I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate x64 with postgresql-x64-9.0. If it's possible to do I'd deeply appreciate some guidance about the steps needed to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to  create [`tablespaces`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html)

like this:

first create desired directory in your partitions (Ex.`D:\\DB_ONE_SPACE`,`G:\\DB_TWO_SPACE`) then create `tablespace` for each

```
 CREATE TABLESPACE space_one
      OWNER postgres
      LOCATION 'D:\\DB_ONE_SPACE';

 CREATE TABLESPACE space_two
      OWNER postgres
      LOCATION 'E:\\DB_TWO_SPACE';
```

and create DB by assigning tablespace for each

```
CREATE DATABASE "DB1"
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = space_one

  CREATE DATABASE "DB2"
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = space_two
```